# Is GitHub Copilot constantly training on private data?

Tags: github

I'm using GitHub Classroom for my class.

I wrote an assignment and pushed it together with the solution to a private repo in my org.

The assignment includes parts of the solution for the students to use as a skeleton.

I'm wondering if in this case, students that use GitHub Copilot, while working on the skeleton, might get autocompletions from Copilot that are taken from the actual solution that I wrote and pushed into the private repo.

Comment: Welcome to the fun. Darn good question, for your case and for Copilot in general. I'll await the answers nearly as eagerly as you.

Comment: Eventually it'll probably wind up used in some training, but likely not during the semester you've deployed it in, and even if it is doesn't mean it'll be regurgitated verbatim. A bit of an aside: I'm surprised there hasn't been more discussion of the implications of LLMs on CSE.se. Isn't it the biggest game-changer to hit CS education in... decades?

Comment: @ggorlen that is very true. It's a game changer on every subject but probably most of all on cs. For now though i think it's still producing enough garbage output that is manageable from educational perspective IMO but the question is how long that will last. However I think this is perhaps more of a reddit type discussion.